# Change Application.Calculation in different Excel process

Tags: excel, vba, windows-process

In a VBA subroutine I write values to another "Target" workbook that runs in a separate Excel process, like this:

```
Set xlWB = GetObject(STR_TARGET_WORKBOOK_FILENAME)
xlWB.Worksheets(STR_TARGET_SHEET).Range("B1").value = Now()
```

I want to suspend calculation in the Target workbook while I write values to it.  If it were running in the same Excel process as this VBA I could just do `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`.

How can I get and set the `Application.Calculation` mode in the Excel process in which the Target workbook is running?

Comment: xlWb will also have an application object. xlWb.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Comment: @Sorceri – that does it!  Want to post as answer I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external workbook object will also have a reference to its Application, so we can simply do:

```
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim calcMode As Integer

Set xlWB = GetObject(STR_TARGET_WORKBOOK_FILENAME)
' Get the Target's calculation mode
calcMode = xlWB.Application.Calculation
' Suspend calculation in the Target's Excel process
xlWB.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
' ... do stuff to xlWB
' Restore whatever calculation mode was in that process
xlWB.Application.Calculation = calcMode
```